# how can i improve performance of javascript functional test in IE8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, functional-testing

when i am running functional test in IE8 i am getting function in IE profiler,which is taking more time,so how can i improve performance of functional test.this are the function which are the most time consuming.

```
poller,
_open ,                          
class,
document loaded,
check for new document,
js script-window script block,
filter,
function.call,
sizzle,
function.apply,
init,
method,
find,
process,
run,
funcunit,
perform sync query,
```

and the test is like this

```
module("test#009 - logo for legacy",{
   set up:function(){
   s.open("/demo/documentation/details/10");}
});

test("logo" ,function(){
   s("div.ui-pagelogo:eq(0)").exists function(){
   ok(true,"div with classname ui-pagelogo exists");
});

s("div.ui-pagelogo:eq(0)>a").exists(function(){
   ok(true,"dive.ui-pagelogo containing anchor tag exists");
});
s(div.ui-pagelogo:eq(0)>a").attr("href","http://www.google.com").existsfunction(){
  ok(true,"anchor tag exist with href attribut(e");
});
s(div.ui-pagelogo:eq(0)>a").attr("title","symbol of unity").existsfunction(){
  ok(true,"anchor tag exist with title attribute");
});
```